# warning: '*' in boolean context, suggest '&&' instead [-Wint-in-bool-context]?

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings

i've this code (which is pretty all "float"):

```
#define sincf(x) (x == 0.0f) ? (1.0f) : (sinf(M_PI * x) / (M_PI * x))
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < num_taps; i++)
    proto[i] = 2.0f * f * sincf(2.0f * f * (i - m / 2.0f));
// ...
```

why gcc says *warning: '*' in boolean context, suggest '&&' instead [-Wint-in-bool-context]* for the second "*"?

- f is float
- proto is *float
- i and m are int

Comment: Remember the macro expansion is *literal*. In the macro, using `(x)` instead of `x` will probably “fix” the issue.

Comment: `x == 0.0f` is unlikely to ever be true, unless you explicitly use `sincf(0.0f)`.

Comment: And in C++ there's almost *never* a need to use function-like macros instead of actual functions.

Comment: In C++, you should simply avoid #define. There are always better ways to do what you want to do...

Comment: Can't reproduce.    Rather than force people to make wild guesses about what you might have omitted that is relevant to your problem, try providing a [mcve].

Comment: @Peter [Reproduced](https://godbolt.org/z/nzGxofPeW)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the macro has been substituted, this part

```
2.0f * f * sincf(2.0f * f * (i - m / 2.0f));
```

becomes

```
 2.0f * f * (2.0f * f * (i - m / 2.0f) == 0.0f) ? ...
```

and according to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the multiplication `2.0f * f * condition` will be done before checking if the condition is `true` (with `?`). Like so:

```
(2.0f * f * (2.0f * f * (i - m / 2.0f) == 0.0f)) ? ...
```

The quick fix:

```
#define sincf(x) (((x) == 0.0f) ? (1.0f) : (sinf(M_PI * (x)) / (M_PI * (x))))
```

`(x) == 0.0f` will rarely be `true` but since it's only used to avoid division by zero, that's probably fine.

Now, this could easily be rewritten as a *function* and I suggest doing that. Example:

```
template<class T>
T sinc(T x) {
    if(x == T{}) return {1}; // avoid division by zero
    auto pix = static_cast<T>(M_PI) * x;
    return std::sin(pix) / pix;
}
```

One could also cast `x` to `double` if `T` is an integral type. Here's a C++20 version of that:

```
#include <concepts> // std::integral
#include <numbers>  // std::numbers::pi_v

template<class T>
T sinc(T x) {
    if(x == T{}) return 1; // avoid division by zero
    // C++20 added some constants to the standard library:
    auto pix = std::numbers::pi_v<T> * x;
    return std::sin(pix) / pix;
}

double sinc(std::integral auto x) {
    return sinc<double>(x);
}
```